# Iterative segment tree implmentation

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, segment-tree

I'm referring to this post : 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-efficient-implementation/

Pasting the code here for reference. My questions are below the code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// limit for array size 
const int N = 100000; 

int n; // array size 

// Max size of tree 
int tree[2 * N]; 

// function to build the tree 
void build( int arr[]) 
{ 
    // insert leaf nodes in tree 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)  
        tree[n+i] = arr[i]; 

    // build the tree by calculating parents 
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i)  
        tree[i] = tree[i<<1] + tree[i<<1 | 1];   
} 

// function to update a tree node 
void updateTreeNode(int p, int value) 
{ 
    // set value at position p 
    tree[p+n] = value;              // {Question} Why is this assigned before updating the parent index to access?
    p = p+n;

    // move upward and update parents 
    for (int i=p; i > 1; i >>= 1) 
        tree[i>>1] = tree[i] + tree[i^1]; 
} 

// function to get sum on interval [l, r) 
int query(int l, int r) 
{ 
    int res = 0; 

    // loop to find the sum in the range 
    for (l += n, r += n; l < r; l >>= 1, r >>= 1) 
    { 
        if (l&1) 
            res += tree[l++]; 

        if (r&1) 
            res += tree[--r];
        // {Question} What happens if !(l&1) or !(r&1) ? res is not accumulated anywhere. Isn't this wrong?
    } 


    return res; 
} 

// driver program to test the above function 
int main() 
{ 
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}; 

    // n is global 
    n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); 

    // build tree 
    build(a); 

    // print the sum in range(1,2) index-based 
    cout << query(1, 3)<<endl; 

    // modify element at 2nd index 
    updateTreeNode(2, 1); 

    // print the sum in range(1,2) index-based 
    cout << query(1, 3)<<endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Questions:

1. Within `updateTreeNode` where value is being set to parent,
   why is the parent being incremented by array size *after* assigning the value in the tree?
   Shouldn't it be before?
   The original line of code this post has implemented this from reads like this: 
   `for (tree[parent += n] = value; parent > 1; parent >>= 1)`
   where `parent=parent+n` executes first.
   Can someone help me understand why this code is still functioning properly?
2. Within `query` which returns a sum in the interval [l, r), this code seems to add
   result only for odd values of `l`.
   Yet, I see that the result correctly returns the sum for even-valued-intervals.

   The result should be skipping accumulating even-valued intervals since there is no `else <accumulate result>`, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

The variable `p` doesn't mean parent, it means child. In `for` loop, `i` is child node, and we update value of `i`'s parent.

`tree[p+n] = value;`: update the value of leave node (node without children). Then we update value of node's parent from the leave node. `tree[i>>1] = tree[i] + tree[i^1];`, `tree[i>>1]` is `tree[i]`' parent.

For example: the array size is 16 (the tree size is 32) and I want to update arr[8]. So I call `updateTreeNode(8, value)`. First `three[8+16]` is updated, which corresponds to `arr[8]`. Then `p` is set to 24. In for loop, we update p's parent (tree[12]), then set p to p/2 (p=12), until p doesn't have parent.

### Qustion 2

If `l` and `r` is even, we add the parent's value in next recurrence. That's the function of segment tree, to avoid querying each element in the interval.

For example: the array size is 16 and I want to query [8,10). In segment tree, the interval is [24,26). We don't need to add value of `tree[24]` and `tree[25]`, we add value of `tree[12]`!